# BigQuery -- Problem Using UDF in publicly shared project

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I am having trouble understanding why I cannot use a UDF that is shared publicly. I am interested in using the UDFs available in the public project "jslibs" as described for example here:

https://carto.com/blog/spatial-functions-bigquery-uber/

If I execute the following SQL in the BigQuery SQL UI:

`SELECT jslibs.h3.ST_H3(ST_GEOGPOINT(-74.00,40.7128),7)`

It runs just fine.

However, if I try to use the same function against data from a table in my own dataset, I get an error that the function cannot be found.

Example:

```
SELECT a.*, jslibs.h3.ST_H3(ST_GEOGPOINT(-74.00,40.7128),7) 
from bargetracker.ais a where dt_utc = '2019-01-01' limit 10
```

This results in an error "Function not found: jslibs.h3.ST_H3 at [1:13]"

Anybody know why this gives an error?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here (after a lot of searching):

UDFs **cannot** be shared across regions. This thread from Github gives the answer:

https://github.com/CartoDB/carto-spatial-extension/issues/46